# HOW do i filter out the latests runs in and crosstab the rowns into columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

```
| product | tests | runs | results |
|---------|-------|------|---------|
| A       | AD    | 1    | 12      |
| A       | AD    | 2    | 13      |
| A       | AD    | 3    | 14      |
| A       | SS    | 1    | 12      |
| A       | TD    | 1    | 12      |
| A       | TD    | 2    | 12      |
| B       | AD    | 1    | 11      |
| B       | SS    | 1    | 12      |
| c       | AD    | 1    | 12      |
| c       | AD    | 2    | 10      |
| D       | AD    | 1    | 16      |
| D       | SS    | 1    | 12      |
```

I used this query:

```
select DISTINCT Poduct,
    SUM (case param_name when 'AD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS AD,
    SUM (case param_name when 'SS' then results ELSE 0 END) AS SS,
    SUM (case param_name when 'TD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS TD
FROM [product]
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product
```

To get it in this format:

```
| PRODUCT | AD | SS | TD |
|---------|----|----|----|
| A       | 39 | 12 | 24 |
| B       | 11 | 12 | 0  |
| C       | 22 | 0  | 0  |
| D       | 16 | 12 | 0  |
```

I need it in this format, but the problem is that it's adding up all the test runs on AD, SS, and TD.

What I'm looking for is this:

```
| PRODUCT | AD | SS | TD |
|---------|----|----|----|
| A       | 14 | 12 | 12 |
| B       | 11 | 12 | 0  |
| C       | 10 | 0  | 0  |
| D       | 16 | 12 | 0  |
```

Which is pulling only the results from the greater run of that test.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Quick guess: lose the DISTINCT, your GROUP BY does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select product, max(ad) ad, max(ss) ss, max(td) td
from (
  select Product,
      MAX(case tests when 'AD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS AD,
      MAX(case tests when 'SS' then results ELSE 0 END) AS SS,
      MAX(case tests when 'TD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS TD
  FROM product
  GROUP BY product, tests
) test_reports
group by product
ORDER BY product;
```

**Demo** @ [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e915/12)

Answer (score 0):

I think, assuming fro your expected result, you are wanting to `SUM` on those columns (`AD,SS,TD`) based on your highest `RUN` number. You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign the order based on your requirement and choose the right values set

Try this...

```
WITH CTE AS 
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY product,test order by runs desc) rownum FROM product
)
select Product,
    SUM (case test when 'AD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS AD,
    SUM (case test when 'SS' then results ELSE 0 END) AS SS,
    SUM (case test when 'TD' then results ELSE 0 END) AS TD
FROM CTE
WHERE rownum=1
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product
```

Comment: I tried out your code and all my tests results for AD, SS, and TD came out to be '0'. Also I got a Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Rownum'. on the WHERE clause @SoulTrain

Comment: Are they what you expected?

Comment: I missed the mssql tag, I will rewrite it for mysql

Comment: OK, I got the results to show up, but THE only problem i'm having is in the WHERE rownum = 1 I put WHERE run = 1 and that doesn't work for what I need, because PRODUCT A needs to show me the result for test AD run 3 and test SS run 1 and that WHERE will only show me run 1.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to think of a temporary table that has the following fields: product, tests, and max_runs. (i.e. identifying the max run # for each combination of product + tests). If you have such a table, you can JOIN it back to the original (inner join) to select only the row with the max run#.

Then, using your case statement on the result will work.

Putting it all together, you would get this:

```
select P.product, 
    sum(case P.tests when 'AD' then P.results ELSE 0 END) AS AD,
    sum(case P.tests when 'SS' then P.results ELSE 0 END) AS SS,
    sum(case P.tests when 'TD' then P.results ELSE 0 END) AS TD
from product P join 
(
SELECT product, tests, max(runs) As max_runs
from product
group by product, tests
  ) As M
on P.product=M.product and P.tests=M.tests and P.runs=M.max_runs
group by P.product
order by P.product
```

Check out [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60e76/14) if you want to play with it.